# Is there a way to add ascending or decsending numbers into multiple text files at once?

Tags: notepad++

I have 100 notepad files having text like this:

> "john is going home
>   his door number is **0001**"

Note: number **0001 or any other number** has been applied in all 100 text documents.

In all the remaining files the door number has to be changed to 0002 , 0003, 0004. etc. I don't want to change it by opening each file for 100 times but I need it to be done at once without editing all one by one. In Notepad++ there is replace option but I have no idea of how to work and not pretty sure this can be done. Can this doubt be cleared in Notepad++? or is there any other software available to do this?

Comment: So `text1.txt` would have `"john is going home his door number is 0001"`, `text2.txt` would have `"john is going home his door number is 0002"`, `text3.txt` would have `"john is going home his door number is 0003"`, and so on ... or they _all_ need to have `"john is going home his door number is 0001"`?

Comment: thanks for the reply. your first guess is correct. text2.txt would have "john is going home his door number is 0002", text3.txt would have "john is going home his door number is 0003", and so on.

Comment: Is it possible with notepad++? or any suggestion?

Comment: You can use [notepad++ to capture and replace values using regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286068/regex-find-replace-in-notepad), so you could find and replace all with "john...0001", but I don't know if you can do an incremental replace like you're wanting .. you could do this fairly easy with a VBScript if you're comfortable with scripting though ..

Comment: thanks. im not good enough skilled in Vbscript but i know a little bit of it. I think i need to do tough research over internet to find out solution for this task. lets see. thanks once again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether you have access to a Unix environment or Cygwin under Windows, but I think this little bash script that I recycled from an old script I wrote and modified for your example does the work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in {1..100}
    do
        digs=${#line}
        zeros=$((4 - $digs))
        zeros2=$(yes 0 | head -$zeros | paste -s -d '' -)
        numm=$zeros2$line
        printf "john is going home\nhis door number is %s\n" $numm > text$numm.txt
    done
```

Comment: thank you Cevikel, this is the method what im exactly looking for but i hv not yet tried it out as im not that familiar to Unix environment and Cygwin, so, first i need to install Cygwin under windows then will go through your workout. Im gonna google how to save this bash script from Cygwin to a file then run it. i hv almost got a help from u. i ll give it a try then let u know. if u can spare some more time pls do let me know how to save this file and run it in win 7. thank u friend

Comment: I'll try to figure out a way to port this script to Windows Shell.

Comment: hope you can do it

Comment: I hv installed Cygwin under windows 7. Can u let me know how to run this bash script? thanks

Comment: You save the script into a file (preferably with a .sh extension). The first line should be `#!/bin/bash` if the default shell of your user is bash. You make the script executable with `chmod +x /path/to script`. Now by typing the path to the script you can execute it. To make the script a command to be executable anywhere, you should put a symlink to one of the paths stated in your $PATH environment variable. Fox example: `ln -s /path/to/script /usr/bin/your_command`